# What geographic location is shown in the macOS High Sierra default desktop image?

Tags: macos, high-sierra, desktop, screensaver

Looks like Convict Lake, just off US395 in Mono County...but I'm guessing.

Does anyone know where the fall mountain scene with the lake was photographed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [this person](https://discussions.apple.com/message/32291617#32291617), it's in [North Lake in Bishop, CA](https://www.google.com/maps/place/North+Lake/@37.2313494,-118.6167944,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x80be21327e4dd4e3:0xfb6e74f3a13f8595!8m2!3d37.231593!4d-118.6144454).

Comment: Yes, that looks right, thanks. While the link in the answer doesn't display a picture, a Google Images search for "North Lake, Bishop CA" returns lots of pics showing the same scene.

Comment: I added the link to Google maps to show where it was. On the left side of that page is a section named Photos that takes you to hundreds of professional and amateur photos of the area.